# IE9 jQuery Image Size?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

This code snippet doesn't work on IE9. In the HTML I declare the width and the height of images, however when the code runs it alerts 0 instead of the image sized specified in the attribute. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Works fine on Chrome / Firefox

```
// Sets Default Size to a data attr
function saveImageDefaults() {
    $('#rightBlock img').each(function() {
        alert($(this).attr('width'));
    });
}

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    // Resize Right Block
    $('#rightBlock').width($('#whiteBlockIn').width() - 270);


    // Save Images Default  Width / Height
    saveImageDefaults();
}
```

Comment: Are your images visible?

Comment: Two questions:
Does your code work with the previous version of ie 9 (8, 7, 6)? And can you post the html code please?

Comment: Which version of jQuery?

Comment: All versions of IE, latest jQuery whatever that is.. images are visible till IE sets the width / height to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `jQuery` is returning the computed style, which is when the element is rendered. However, IE has `elem.currentStyle` which - as far as I can remember - differs from `elem.runtimeStyle` (which is similar to `getComputedStyle()`).

So, try `this.currentStyle.width` to see what it returns

Comment: IE 9 supports `getComputedStyle()`.

Answer (score 1):

If it was working in IE8, you can use

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" />
```

as quick and dirty solution.

Comment: yes it works with IE8. I did test it for a couple of seconds.

Comment: it *might* fix that problem, but then you'd also lose all the other new and shiny IE9 features. It'd kinda defeat the point of having upgraded to IE9.

Comment: @Spudley of course you're right, but I've noticed that it's quick but dirty.